# Apache ins't loading WebGL content

Tags: javascript, apache, unity-game-engine

I have a WebGL game built in Unity that works fine locally, but I want to host it on my new Apache2.4 server. I have moved the files across to the server, but when I load the page everything loads except the WebGL content (see screenshot below).

The dev tools tell me that the UnityProgress.js and UnityLoader.js files failed to load with a 404 error code. The case sensitivity is correct for the files and folders names to the html in the Unity generated index.html (I would be surprised if that was incorrect). I have tried moving them out of their subfolders and placing them next to my index.html file and updating the html, but I am still get the same message.

Am I missing a setting on my Apache server for the .js files to load?

[image]

EDIT: Below is the contents of the index.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | WebGLClock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="UnityProgress.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="template">
    <p class="header"><span>Unity WebGL Player | </span>WebGLClock</p>
    <div class="template-wrap clear">
      <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>
      <br>
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="fullscreen"><img src="fullscreen.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Fullscreen" title="Fullscreen" onclick="SetFullscreen(1);" /></div>
      <div class="title">WebGLClock</div>
    </div>
    <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  var Module = {
    TOTAL_MEMORY: 268435456,
    errorhandler: null,         // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
    compatibilitycheck: null,
    dataUrl: "Bin WebGL.data",
    codeUrl: "Bin WebGL.js",
    memUrl: "Bin WebGL.mem",

  };
</script>
<script src="UnityLoader.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And a picture of the folder structure from /var/www/html.

[image]

Comment: A 404 error normally indicates that no file exists at the requested path. Based on that, I'd recommend checking if the paths are specified correctly. Unity builds normally specify path information in the generated HTML file.

Comment: try posting the relevant part of the HTML file

Comment: I have added both the html file source and screenshot of the folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Linux distro comes with lighttpd. It is another webserver that was intercepting all of the port 80 traffic.

Running the following command fixed things:

```
sudo apt-get remove lighttpd
```